How can I make an environment variable accessible to a nodejs process hosted in Kubernetes?
I am trying to host my own instance of Lighthouse-CI and the Lighthouse report viewer. By default, Lighthouse-CI automatically opens the report viewer on Google's GitHub, but for security reasons I am hosting my own.
Lighthouse-CI checks for the node environment variable VIEWER_ORIGIN, but I'm unsure how to set it when it's being hosted in k8s. Here's the relevant line in Lighthouse-CI's server code.
I've tried adding VIEWER_ORIGIN to my k8s deployment for my server, and it's showing correctly when I describe the pod, but it's not reflecting at all in the actual application. Here's my current config:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: lhci-deployment
  labels:
    app: server
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: server
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: server
    spec: 
      containers:
      - name: lhci
        image: patrickhulce/lhci-server:0.13.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9001
        env: 
        - name: VIEWER_ORIGIN
          value: 'example.com'


If you exec into the pod and run the command env, do you see this variable with the correct value assigned?

Yes, VIEWER_ORIGIN is shown with the correct value. In that case, this is likely related more to getting the env variable picked up by LHCI.

Turns out that yes, the problem ended up being Lighthouse specific - the env variable that I wanted to set is only evaluated at build time, not run time. This was actually changed in a very recent MR, which you can see here.
